# How to get row total of each product in an order on Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm trying to get the subtotal of each row/line item in the success page but I'm not sure what to use.
I've tried `getRowTotal()` and `getRowTotalInclTax()` but both are showing up blank.
I'm able to get the whole cart subtotal but want I need is the individual product subtotal.

Here's part of the code I'm using:

```
// Get order details
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());

// Get Each Product Details
$items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $i) {
  $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($i->getProductId());

  echo $product->getName();
  echo $product->getSku();
  echo $product->getRowTotal(); // This is where its just coming back blank/null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you are loading the product entity: The product entity cannot contain the information of the order.
You must use the Order Item entity that you already use to have the total row

Something like this :

```
// Get order details
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());

// Get Each Product Details
$items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $i) {
  echo $i->getProduct()->getName();
  echo $i->getProduct()->getSku();
  echo $i->getRowTotal(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried this. Although I'm not getting blank anymore I'm now getting 0.00

Comment: Does it return 0 for all items?
Normally it returns 0 when it is a configurable product, you should get the value of the simple product

Comment: Yup you're right I'm trying to get the rowTotal for configurable products